# Republishing AGS Service Doesn't Update Web Map in AGOL

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, layers, update, map-service

I created a web map in my AGOL content folder after publishing from ArcMap as a Portal feature service. I created a web map in AGOL by bringing in the service URL. I have three group layers with several layers within each group. In the AGOL map viewer, I went through each layer and configured the popups and symbology. After I had done this, I needed to add a new layer to one of the groups, so I added it to my MXD group layer of interest, republished the service and then went to the web map that is fed from this service.

The web map doesn't update with the new layer, so I was trying to figure out how to update the web map without having to recreate the entire thing in AGOL. I don't want to really do this each time I have to add a new layer in the MXD because of the configurations I have on each layer with the popups and symbology.

Am I missing some process/option to refresh the TOC so that it adds the changes I made to the service?

In ArcMap my TOC looks like this with the new layer highlighted:

[image]

But after republishing, the TOC in AGOL map viewer only shows 3 of the 4 layers:

[image]

I have the Refresh Interval activated to 6 seconds. I've tried publishing several times as a map service, signing in/out of AGOL, etc.

Comment: Hmm that is strange,  I was under the impression if you added a layer to a mapservice and republished the service from the mxd that it would pull the new layer through into the webmap without any changes, guess i was wrong.  Out of curiousity, what would happen if you delete the mapservice layers and then re-add them.  Also have your checked your servername/arcgis/rest/services/AGO_foldername to see if the new service has all the layers your published in it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding a new layer to the service it wont show up in the web map as it wont be in the JSON of the web map. The web map will be referencing the layers that have been added to the map.

It appears if I'm understanding your question correctly, that this approach you are looking to do is unfortunately a problem yet to be solved/offered by Esri at this time based on these Esri forum threads active in late 2018:

[ArcGIS Online overwrite Feature Service from ArcGIS Enterprise and New layer does not show up in AGOL Web Map](https://community.esri.com/thread/219119-arcgis-online-overwrite-feature-service-from-arcgis-enterprise-and-new-layer-does-not-show-up-in-agol-web-map)

[New AGS Mapservice Layers Not Showing in AGOL WebMap](https://community.esri.com/thread/215875-new-ags-mapservice-layers-not-showing-in-agol-webmap)

[#ENH-000108149 [Enhancement] Allow the option to refresh or reset a service in a web map](https://community.esri.com/ideas/15372-enh-000108149-enhancement-allow-the-option-to-refresh-or-reset-a-service-in-a-web-map)